# i18n on custom elements with @bindable does not work with 't.bind'

Tags: aurelia

I've noticed a similar issue has been fixed in https://github.com/aurelia/i18n/issues/123. But it was an issue in 't/i18n' with literal values.

But I'm facing an issue with 't.bind'
We have a use case in which we need to construct the expression and bind it to 't/i18n'

e.g:

`<template>
    <my-custom-element t.bind="messagekey" t-params.bind="{ param1: 10, param2: 10 }"></my-custom-element>
    <my-custom-element t.bind="messagekey"></my-custom-element>
 </template>`

In the view-model we construct the messagekey as bellow:

`this.messagekey = "[title]content_key";`

When you run the application nothing is being written to the custom-element.

However, I tried this with 't' with literal values;

`<template>
  <my-custom-element t="[title]content_key" t-params.bind="{ param1: 10, param2: 10 }"></my-custom-element>
  <my-custom-element t="[title]content_key"></my-custom-element>
</template>`

and it worked.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Just to have this one handled, it sounded like a side effect not related to the i18n plugin. https://github.com/aurelia/i18n/issues/226